# jqueryLazy not triggering when images gets visibles via css changes

Tags: jquery-lazyload

I have a bunch of images, say 100 images, in a web page, and only 10 are visible without scrolling the page. The first 90 images have a "myclass" class.

I manage all images with jquery lazy (http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/), and it works perfecty if I scroll the window.

However, If I make `$(".myclass").hide()` before scrolling down, I see the last 10 images, which don't have the "myclass" class, bug jquery lazy doesn't "reveal" them.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because lazyload triggers on scroll events.

`$(window).scroll()` (which triggers the scroll event on the `window`) is enough to solve the issue.

If the scrollable div is not the window object, use it instead of `$(window)`.